# Dispatch LUIS and QnA Maker in Botframework V4 C#

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to add LUIS and QnA Maker in a bot with dispatch and I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) guide. But in this part is said type or namespace cannot be found. I am using Botframework V4 with latest updates. It said in the guide that it is for Botframework v4 but i think it is outdated.

Hoping someone guides me to properly configure dispatch luis and qna maker. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Show potential fixes"? What happens? That error tells you you are missing a `using ....;` directive

Comment: It just says "generate class QnAMakerEndpoint" in a new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `QnAMakerEndpoint` and `QnAMaker` you need to add [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA/) `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA` to your project and add the `using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;` statement to your code.

[image: Add nuget package for QnA]

Comment: Sir can i ask in the guide. where did "qna" come from? The "qna"s inside qnaendpoint.

Comment: Do you mean `qna.KbId`, `qna.EndpointKey` and `qna.Hostname`? If so, this is coming from configuration in the `*.bot?` If so, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-file-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) is where to start